# Не записываются значения в ячейку БД

Tags: форма, php, mysql

Помогите найти ошибку! В БД ячейка создается, но значения не записываются. Как исправить?

```
<?
    if ($_COOKIE["TestCookie"] == NULL)
    {

    $value = 'что-то где-то';
    setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
    ?>
    <div id="footer">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="price">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    <?
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $ttt = mysql_select_db("testi3", $db);
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trans");
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO trans(name, price) VALUES(name, price)"; 
    mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Вы можете добавить еще одно сообщение только завтра!";
    }
?>
```

**Обновление**

Если написать

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO trans(name, price) VALUES({'$name'}, {'$price'})";
```

Выдает ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''}, {''})' at line 1 или я не так понял?

Comment: @mkrichet1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = sprintf('INSERT INTO trans (name, price) VALUES (\'%s\', \'%s\')', $name, $price);
```

**Обновление**

Потому что запрос у вас записывается в $query, а на исполнение отдается $strSQL. Мой комментарий не приносит ничего нового, кроме читаемости кода.

Comment: @Etki я бы не додумался. %)

Comment: Так вообще не добавляет в БД
...
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trans");
 
 $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO trans (name, price) VALUES (\'%s\', \'%s\')', $name, $price);
 
 mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
 }
...

Answer (score 0):

Значения из формы передаются методом post, но в коде я не увидел, где ты получаешь переменные из глобального массива `$_POST`, чтобы записать их в БД. В строке `$strSQL=.....` должны указываться переменные `$name` и `$price`.

**Обновление**

```
$strSQL = 'INSERT INTO trans(name,price) VALUES("'.$name.'","'.$price.'")';
```

Только переменные `$name` и `$price` еще определить надо.

Answer (score 0):

Решение вашей проблемы

```
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

$strSQL = "INSERT INTO trans (name, price) VALUES($_POST['name'], $_POST['price'])";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 1


...

 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trans");
 
 $_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

$strSQL = "INSERT INTO trans (name, price) VALUES(".$_POST['name'].", ".$_POST['price'].")";
 
 mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
...

Comment: @mkrichet1 поправил, попробуй. :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in Z:\home\intim.ua\www\add-content.php on line 26